# Docker build npm error logs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker

If a `npm install` command fails while building a `Dockerfile`, how can I view the contents of npm-debug.log?  My problems are exacerbating because they only take place on Elastic Beanstalk app uploads, but the question still applies for local docker builds.

Answer (score 16):

The best way would be to run `docker build --rm=false .` in order to keep intermediary image and start bash from the last success build step then run the `npm install` from there.

Alternatively, you can also `docker commit <id>` with the id of the container which ran `npm install`. Example:

```
Step 9 : RUN  npm install
---> Running in 2955a741027a
blablabla
FAIL
$> docker commit 2955a741027a test && docker run -it test cat /path/to/npm-debug.log
```