# Cant Build a Docker, because NPM fails?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, npm

im trying to Build a APP with Docker, but it fails for NPM problems, and im not sure whats the problem?

it even says NPM is outdated but i updated it already...
the CLI also cant or wont make a logfile for this

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# docker build -t booru ./booru
[+] Building 16.5s (9/19)                                                                                                                                                                                                     docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 685B                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                                                                                                                                       0.3s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 45B                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.67kB                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine@sha256:ca9f6cb0466f9638e59e0c249d335a07c867cd50c429b5c7830dda1bed584649                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [builder  2/10] WORKDIR /build                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [builder  3/10] ADD ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [builder  4/10] RUN npm ci                                                                                                                                                                                                   16.1s
------
 > [builder  4/10] RUN npm ci:
15.89 npm notice
15.89 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.4.0
15.89 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.4.0>
15.89 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.4.0` to update!
15.89 npm notice
15.90 npm ERR! code 1
15.90 npm ERR! path /build/node_modules/sharp
15.90 npm ERR! command failed
15.90 npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
15.90 npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
15.90 npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: Invalid Version: 1.2.4_git20230717
15.90
15.90 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-02-27T10_19_21_922Z-debug-0.log
------
WARNING: current commit information was not captured by the build: failed to read current commit information with git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |
   5 |     ADD ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./
   6 | >>> RUN npm ci
   7 |
   8 |     ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_NO_INDEX
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm ci" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
root@ubuntu:/var/www/html# dir /root/.npm/_logs/
root@ubuntu:/var/www/html#
```

Update an APP with Docker and NPM

Comment: The NPM notice to update your version is not an error but a notice. Have you tried to inspect the og file mentionned ? `/root/.npm/_logs/2024-02-27T10_19_21_922Z-debug-0.log`

Comment: yes, but for some  reason there is no such log file, the folder is empty :(

Comment: The logs are located in the container as you run the npm command within the build. See: [Docker Build Npm Error Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192210/docker-build-npm-error-logs) to retrieve your npm logs and edit your question to add them if possible

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dependencies are messed up `Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies` .  But also, you have updated npm but not to the latest version. Try these, making sure all dependencies are installed and updated and update is if it hasn’t fixed it

Comment: Thanks i did 

`xxxx@ubuntu:/var/www/html$ sudo npm install -g npm@10.4.0

changed 14 packages in 2s

24 packages are looking for funding
  run npm fund for details`

but it still says 

`15.60 npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.4.0 to update!`

Comment: It's because you updated your npm on host device, the notice is for the npm version inside your container so you'll have to update your npm version in your container before running the `RUN npm ci`